# Script isn't detecting a change with a BoolValue (Roblox Studio)

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a procedurally generating game (ignore the goal of the game).

Currently I'm trying to make it so when you walk over a grid piece and collide with an invisible part it makes that specific grid piece the Current Global Object (CGO).

Using a BoolValue I made it possible to use this as some form of global variable, but whenever I try to use said value it only detects it as false even when it is indeed showing as true in the Explorer. It only works when I set the value to true BEFORE testing the game.

Here's the code in the script that's meant to detect the value:

it's a regular script and not a LocalScript fyi

```
local CGO = "0,0"
local tracker = game.Workspace.Tracker00
--local CGOa = tracker.CGOa

local trackerPos = tracker.Position
local trackerX = trackerPos.X
local trackerY = trackerPos.Y
local trackerZ = trackerPos.Z

while true do

    while tracker.CGOa.Value == false do
        tracker.YVal.Value = 7
        print("Set TrackerYVal to 7")
        wait()
        if tracker.CGOa.Value == true then
            break
        end
    end

    while tracker.CGOa.Value == true do
        tracker.YVal.Value = 14
        print("Set TrackerYVal to 14")
        wait()
    end

    tracker.CFrame = CFrame.new(trackerX, trackerY, trackerZ)
    wait()

end
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using infinite while loops, consider listening for the Changed signal. It's possible that the `break` command might be escaping both loops.

```
local tracker = game.Workspace.Tracker00

tracker.CGOa.Changed:Connect(function(newVal)
    print("CGOa changed to ", newVal)
    if newVal then
        tracker.YVal.Value = 14
        print("Set TrackerYVal to 14")
    else
        tracker.YVal.Value = 7
        print("Set TrackerYVal to 7")
    end

    -- update the tracker position based on newly updated values
    local x = tracker.XVal.Value
    local y = tracker.YVal.Value
    local x = tracker.ZVal.Value
    tracker.CFrame = CFrame.new(Vector3.new(x, y, z))
end)
```

I made some assumptions about how you were positioning the tracker, because the old code would reset its position after every loop.

Comment: For the positioning it mainly just moves the part upwards out of touching reach (so it would be above a ceiling) and you can probably ignore it but I wouldn't mind some suggestions. 

My main issue is the fact that it only detects the CGOa as false when it should be true, once I can fix that problem I can take the rest from there, so all of the while loops and stuff I'll deal with when I get it to work properly.

Though I will try out your idea and see how it goes.

Comment: I went back into the game to try out your code, everything else went fine except it doesn't detect the change at all.

Comment: What code is actually changing the CGOa's Value? Could you update your question to include that?  You aren't modifying the value in a LocalScript are you?

Comment: I was, but luckily I got a friend to help me out and now I got it all to work in the same script.